# Dropbox Access Token Expiry

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

What is the lifetime for an Access Token acquired through the Dropbox oAuth2 APIs?

The answer after the https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token was something like

```
{
    "access_token": "fHUlx32x494RmgTlxWiF6pLzd5q1Lg4Itt7I6itVYDIDT",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "uid": "17233223324"
}
```

But there's no mention of when the AT expires. If ever.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It effectively never expires. But users can invalidate tokens by unlinking an app. (In the case of an App folder app, they can delete the app folder from their Dropbox. For all apps, they can unlink the app on dropbox.com.)

Comment: Nothing has changed here.

Comment: It was a problem at the Dropbox end, they had some issues which they've now fixed. I submitted a ticket via a link you posted in a comment on another question. All good now, thanks for the help.

Comment: In the case of being a App folder app, if they delete the folder, the app will be unlinked?