# Dropbox API - how to connect without logging into Dropbox every time?

Tags: c#, dropbox

I am working on a proof of concept for reading files from Dropbox.  This is a console app in C#.

All of the 3rd-party tools and examples that I find have this terrible bit of code where the app launches a browser and requires the user to authorize access to Dropbox.

Examples:

- [DevDefined](https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth-Examples/blob/master/src/ExampleDropBoxUpload/Program.cs)
- [Spring](http://cgeers.com/2011/12/29/dropbox-rest-api-part-1-authentication/)
- [Otherwise good blog](http://www.springframework.net/social-dropbox/refdoc/api.html)

All of these examples seem to miss the point.

The problem is - I have already authorized Dropbox access from my app, and I never want to have to do that again!

I have tokens and secrets, but is there any way that I can re-use the ones I already got?  I want to be able to run this demo and get a list of files - just that.  No extra login.

Comment: Tokens expire, so no you cant reuse them past the expiry.  Even Pins to get the token are usually one-use things.  Logging in to get permission is part of the core OAuth model.

Answer (score 1):

Use an access token, which you can generate on your dropbox application's page in the "Generated access token" section.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps

It seems the token does not expire:
[Dropbox Access Token Expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400244/dropbox-access-token-expiry)

Using the Dropbox.Net library you can just use the token when creating a new client.

`using (var dbx = new DropboxClient("YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"))`

More info:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#install

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it looks like  I can take Christophe Greer's example and turn off the call to open a web browser. 
Then I add a header of this form:

```
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization:Bearer <the very long token>");
```

I get this token from Dropbox itself by getting a Generated access token from the application settings page [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/94/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account).

This lets me continue on evaluating the API!

Comment: That's correct, the Dropbox API supports OAuth 1 and OAuth 2, and you can and should store and re-use the user's access token for future API calls for that user. The access tokens don't expire by themselves, but they can be revoked by the user, e.g., via https://www.dropbox.com/account/security .